# Notification called in the onPostExecute returns null

Tags: android

I am to trying to create a notification message, when a background services has been completed,
I therefore call the alert message in the `onPostExecute` within the Async Task extended class.
Below are the methods.

> UPDATE
>   - For better understanding of what i want to achieve and for future purposes I have edited my work to contain all the neccessary information needed. Thanks

```
 public class GCMIntentService extends GCMBaseIntentService {

private static final String TAG = "GCMIntentService";
 private Context mContext;
    private int NOTIFICATION_ID = 1;
    private Notification mNotification;
    private NotificationManager mNotificationManager;

public GCMIntentService(Context context) {
    super(SENDER_ID);
    this.mContext = context;

    //Get the notification manager
    mNotificationManager = (NotificationManager) mContext.getSystemService(Context.NOTIFICATION_SERVICE);
}



/**
 * Method called on Receiving a new message
 * */
@Override
protected void onMessage(Context context, Intent intent) {
    Log.i(TAG, "Received message");

    new ExecuteAsync().execute();
}


private class ExecuteAsync extends AsyncTask<String, String, JSONArray> {

    @Override
    protected void onPreExecute() {
        super.onPreExecute();
    }

    @Override
    protected JSONArray doInBackground(String... args) {

        DatabaseHandler db = new DatabaseHandler(getApplicationContext()); 
        UserFunctions userFunction = new UserFunctions();
        Context context= GCMIntentService.this;
        String msg = "";
        JSONArray json = null;

        msg = "syncing was succefuull";
        Log.i("GCM",  msg);

        //This gets all the information unread from the server
        json = userFunction.getAllNotices(context);

        /**
         * This inserts data from the server into the local 
         * database when the query of unread data from the 
         * server was successful.
         */
        if(json!=null){ 

            try{
                for(int i = 0; i < json.length(); i++){

                    //Values from the remote database
                    String value = json.getJSONObject(i).getString("userID");
                    String name = json.getJSONObject(i).getString("fName");
                    System.out.println(value);
                    System.out.println(name);

                    //Insert data into the local database
                    db.insertNotices((value),
                                    (name));

                    //Again update the online database that the message has been received
                   userFunction.syncUpdate(context,value);  
                }

            }
            catch (JSONException e) {
                    // TODO Auto-generated catch block
                    e.printStackTrace();
            }
        }
         return json;
     }

   @Override
    protected void onPostExecute(JSONArray json) {
       /**
        * This checks if the on background work was successful
        **/
      if(json != null) {

           System.out.println("json contained a data and it was successful");

           String message = "helllllasdp";
           createNotification("Data download ended abnormally!",message);
      }

     else{
        System.out.println("json was null in the post execute");

      }
    }

   private void createNotification(String contentTitle, String contentText) {

       //Build the notification using Notification.Builder
       Notification.Builder builder = new Notification.Builder(mContext)
       .setSmallIcon(android.R.drawable.stat_sys_download)
       .setAutoCancel(true)
       .setContentTitle(contentTitle)
       .setContentText(contentText);

       //Get current notification
       mNotification = builder.getNotification();

       //Show the notification
       mNotificationManager.notify(NOTIFICATION_ID, mNotification);
   }

}

}
```

I would be much grateful if someone could help me solve this problem. Thanks in advance.

Comment: can you show us whats in the doInBackground method? Whatever is returned from doInBackgroud is passed into onPostExecute. So if your input is null that means doInBackground is returning null.

Comment: I have checked my input, it is not returning null.

Comment: Check the logic flow in the doInBackground task again, or post the logic flow.  onPostExecute is called only after doInBackground has completed.

Comment: upon further examination the only possible places that could throw a NullPointerException is mNotificationManager or mNotification

Comment: I am guessing that either mContext or mNotificationManager was null.  I would have to see your entire AsyncTask so I can see where those fields get set.

Comment: @krislarson I have again updated my question, thus where my mContext and mNotificationManager are set. Thanks

Comment: You'll have to place a breakpoint at line 187 of class GCMIntentService because that is where the problem was raised. The stack trace says it happened in onPostExecute but there is nothing in that method as it is now that would cause a NullPointer

Comment: Have you tried stepping through the code and assuring that userFunction.getAllNotices(context); returns a result other than null? because that has the possibility of setting json to null and returning null.

Comment: Please I have done all these, I even check from the onpostexecute, whether my json return null or not, fortunately it returns not null

Comment: is GCMIntentService is the class which calls the async task ?

Comment: @adhithiyan Yes please

Comment: If the AsyncTask is started from the GCMIntentService then the question is why do you need an AsyncTask at all? IntentServices already run their own worker thread. You should just post the whole service code instead of bits and pieces, that would make it maybe possible to see the whole flow. My assumption is that the service context is invalid once the AsyncTask ends so it's an issue with the lifecycle of the service.

Comment: @EmanuelMoecklin i have updated my work with the full view of what I am doing, I would be grateful i you could your ideas on this. Thank you

Answer (score 0):

```
private class ExecuteAsync extends AsyncTask<Void,Void,Void>
{
    //declare context here
     Context myContext;
     public ExecuteAsync(Context receivedContext)
     {
       this.myContext=receivedContext;
     }
```

**`onPostExecute()` Method**

```
  protected void onPostExecute(JSONArray json) {

           if(json != null) {
             mNotificationManager = (NotificationManager) myContext.getSystemService(Context.NOTIFICATION_SERVICE);
               //Intent intent=new Intent();
               String message = "helllllasdp";
            Notification.Builder builder = new Notification.Builder(mContext)
           .setSmallIcon(android.R.drawable.stat_sys_download)
           .setAutoCancel(true)
           .setContentTitle("Data download ended abnormally!")
           .setContentText(message);

           //Get current notification
           mNotification = builder.getNotification();

           //Show the notification
           mNotificationManager.notify(NOTIFICATION_ID, mNotification);
           }

           else{
               System.out.println("json was null in the post execute");

           }

}
```

**while calling in your `onMessage()` Method**

```
protected void onMessage(Context context, Intent intent) {
    Log.i(TAG, "Received message");

    new ExecuteAsync(context).execute();
}
```

Answer (score 0):

As I mentioned in my comment, IntentService.onHandleIntent (which calls onMessage in this case) runs in a worker thread so there's no need to start an AsyncTask (unlike "normal" services that run in the thread that started them).

What happens here is that the onHandleIntent/onMessage terminates and the service is stopped meaning the context becomes invalid. That's very likely the reason your Notification.Builder builder = new Notification.Builder(mContext) crashes.

Eliminate the AsyncTask and run everything including doInBackground in the onMessage method and you should be good.